# Why does the PiCamera() preview start bright and then immediately get dark when using a low frame rate and high shutter speed?

Tags: camera, raspicam, image

I'm adjusting some of the PiCamera parameters to make it work well in low light. However, when I preview the camera (in low light) the image starts off looking great and then immediately darkens. These are the steps I take:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
cam = picamera.PiCamera()
cam.framerate = 4
cam.shutter_speed = 249839  # max shutter speed for a frame rate of 4. 
cam.start_preview()
```

What's causing the image to go really dark after about a second? Also - if there are better ways to handle low light, would love to hear about those. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have to reset the gain level when continously operating with a high `shutter_speed`.

The docs:

> You can force a longer exposure time with the shutter_speed attribute
>   at which point the scene will become quite washed out (because both
>   the gain and exposure time are now fixed). If you let the gain float
>   again by setting iso back to automatic (0) you should find the gain
>   reduces accordingly and the scene returns more or less to normal.

See the section **6.1.7 Feedback Loops** here:

https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/fov.html